# Angular2 how to correct put request

Tags: json, rest, angular, typescript

Ok then, I have a single problem, the

Request URL:http://.../rest/1.0/brand/test145
Request Method:PUT
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:...

Request payload is ok
{
  "name": "test145"
}

```
addBrand(name : string){
    let body = JSON.stringify(name)
    let url = this.baseUrl + '/brand/' + name;
    return this.http.put(url, { name }  ).
    map(res => res.json());
}

addBrand(name:any){
if(!name){return;}
this.BrandService.addBrand(name)
.subscribe(
    name => this.name.push(name),
    error => this.errorMesage = <any>error);

}
```

But the put should look like http://.../rest/1.0/brand/ and then, should be only request payload. When I remove that "name" from, it doesn't load the payload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stricly PUT is update, so the url should be in format:

http://.../rest/1.0/brand/test145 where the last part is unique id (you need to indicate what you mean to update)

If you expect to create a record, you should rather POST to http://.../rest/1.0/brand

But you can always choose to deviate from conventions. In order to PUT to `.../brand` with a payload `{ "name": "test145" }` you would need to:

```
addBrand(name : string){
    let body = JSON.stringify({ name: name })
    let url = this.baseUrl + '/brand'
    return this.http.put(url, body ).
    map(res => res.json());
}
```